# Taking screenshot of Android screen when app is crashing

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm starting to leverage Visual Studio App Center, and they have a way of uploading a file attachment with each crash report when the app restarts, like so:

```
AppCenter.Start (Resources.GetString (Resource.String.appcenter_app_secret), typeof (Analytics), typeof (Crashes));
            Crashes.GetErrorAttachments = (ErrorReport report) => {
                var logs = new List<ErrorAttachmentLog> ();
                var bytes = ContentHelper.GetBytes (AppCenterLoggingSink.ScreenShotFilePath);
                if (bytes != null && bytes.Any ()) {
                    logs.Add (ErrorAttachmentLog.AttachmentWithBinary (bytes, AppCenterLoggingSink.SCREENSHOT_FILE_NAME, "image/jpeg"));
                    ContentHelper.Delete (AppCenterLoggingSink.ScreenShotFilePath);
                }
                return logs;
            };
```

This led me to think, wouldn't it be cool to take a screenshot of the screen when the app is actually crashing so that I have more insight into what caused the crash? Then I could save it to disk, and attach it to the error report on app restart. I looked up how to take a screenshot of the screen, and it works great when the app is running normally:

```
public static byte[] TakeScreenshot () {
            var activity = ApplicationContext.Activity;
            if (activity == null)
                return null;

            var view = activity.Window.DecorView;
            view.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
            view.BuildDrawingCache ();
            var bitmap = view.DrawingCache;

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream ()) {
                bitmap.Compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 0, stream);
                return stream.ToArray ();
            }
        }
```

However, if I try to execute this code when the app is crashing, it silently fails when calling "var bitmap = view.DrawingCache;". No exceptions are seen in the console, and if I wrap it in a try/catch it never gets to the catch. So something about the app being in a crashed and about to quit state makes it not possible to get the drawing cache.

I'm wondering how I can get around this issue so that I can take screenshots while the app is crashing?

Comment: "The app is crashing", there is very little you can do at that point. Saving the exception/stacktrace to a text file (to be sent on app relaunch) is about the best the process can do. Allocating a glob memory, creating a screen buffer/cache to convert to a jpg, etc... is just not likely to happen AFTER the app process is already in a termination state.

Comment: Disappointing, but I guess it is what it is... If you post your comment as an answer then I'll accept it, thanks.

Comment: @SyshiHangiver please post your comment as an answer .Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!